# Using Named Scopes as Subqueries in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my Rails app, I want to join one table with a named scope of another table. Is there a way to do this without having to rewrite the named scope in pure SQL for my join statement?

Basically, is there a way to do something like this?

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :updated_today, where('updated_at > ?', DateTime.now.prev_day)
end

Bar.joins(Foo.updated_today)
```

Where Bar.joins generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM bars
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT * FROM foos WHERE updated_at > 2012-8-9) AS t0
ON bar_id = bars.id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there's any method specifically designed for doing this. You can, however, use the [`to_sql`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActiveRecord/Relation/to_sql) method of `ActiveRecord::Relation` to get the full SQL Query for the scope as a string, which you can then use as a subquery in a join statement, like so:

```
Bar.joins("INNER JOIN (#{Foo.updated_today.to_sql}) as t0 ON bar_id = bars.id")
```

Comment: Yes, I did just answer my own question. If anyone has a better way of doing this though please feel free to chime in.

Comment: Perfectly acceptable to answer your own question, especially when the rest of us can't seem to do so... :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `merge` method to join scopes to another model's query:

```
Bar.joins(:foos).merge(Foo.updated_today)
```

I haven't seen a ton of documentation on this (the Rails API doesn't even have any documentation on the method itself), but here is a pretty decent [blog post](http://www.alexrothenberg.com/2011/10/17/chaining-active_record-scopes-from-different-models.html) giving a reasonably detailed example.

Also, just noticed that this is mentioned in a RailsCast on [Advanced Queries in Rails 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3?view=asciicast).

Comment: That's really interesting, but it's not quite what I was looking for. I'm not looking to join the scopes to the query, I want to use the query generated by the scope as a subquery which I can call a LEFT OUTER JOIN on. (I'll update the question to make this more clear.)